# Routes with params Angular 6

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

I have a component that is a button and that stores objects in a variable called `Microphones`. And I want the button to pass the object to another component and then show details of that specific object. But it is not working for me.

It is assumed that in my routes I define that the presentation component has a parameter, that parameter I passed it with the button from the line of `[routerLink]`. But in the console it appears to me that the parameter is `undefined`.

## button-menu.component.ts

```
export class ButtonMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()Microfonos:any;
  @Input()NombreClasificacion:any;

  micObj:any

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

## button-menu.component.html

```
<div class="btn-group dropright">
    <button type="button" class="btn beige dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-display="static" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{NombreClasificacion}}</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-left">
        <button *ngFor="let mics of Microfonos" class="dropdown-item beige text-center" type="button" [routerLink]="['/presentacion',mics]">{{mics.nombre}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

## app-routing-module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path:'menu',
  component: MainComponent,
  },
  {
    path:'bajo',
    component: MenuBajoComponent
  },
  {
    path:'guitarra',
    component: MenuGuitarraComponent
  },
  {
    path:'presentacion/:objMic',
    component:PresentacionMicComponent
  }
];
```

```
export class PresentacionMicComponent implements OnInit {

  objMic:any;

  constructor(private rutaActiva:ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.rutaActiva.params.subscribe( params => {
      this.objMic = params['mics'];
    });
    console.log(this.objMic);
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Comment: Route params subscribe is asynchronous, you simply will not be able to console.log after the statement because it will always resolve before subscribe. At minimum put the subscribe inside subscribe body.

Comment: Like tihs? [link](https://gyazo.com/d0ec7a744b2e50f4ec630fb3733c8f67)

Comment: Yes, in terms of logging the params that screenshot demonstrates the proper placement.

Answer (score 0):

first of all @AlexanderStaroselsky is right console.log should be in subscribe

and your button-menu.component.html is wrong too,
if mics is object you should use an property of mics not pass the whole object

this

```
[routerLink]="['/presentacion',**mics**]


<div class="btn-group dropright">
    <button type="button" class="btn beige dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-display="static" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{NombreClasificacion}}</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-left">
        <button *ngFor="let mics of Microfonos" class="dropdown-item beige text-center" type="button" [routerLink]="['/presentacion',**mics**]">{{**mics.nombre**}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean... something like this?

`<button *ngFor="let mics of Microfonos" class="dropdown-item beige text-center" type="button" [routerLink]="['/presentacion',mics.nombre]">{{mics.nombre}}</button>`

I put the console.log inside the subscribe, but it's still show me undefined.

Comment: yes, check your service for mics value i think something wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            queryParams: {
                "par1": parVal1,
                "par2": parVal2,
                "par3": parVal3

            }
        };

this.router.navigate(['/componentName'], navigationExtras)
```